# Use of tautology

Tags: adverbial-phrases

I have read a sentence that SHOCKED me if it is correct. In the sentence I read the verb 'waste' preceding the adverb 'needlessly'.

Can anything be wasted under a need?

Does the adverb 'needlessly' fits with the verb 'waste'?

are the questions revolving in my mind. I believe it's either tautology or maybe something else, even it seems to be incorrect too, or whatever I am not sure but what I am sure of is that these two can't come together. Am I right?

Comment: Well., I suppose food could be counted as 'wasted' if it had to be thrown away because it had gone bad.

Comment: In preparing food, parts are discarded as waste, for example cartilege. In a corn threshing machine, the waste parts of the crop are separated. In manufacturing, some of the products are substandard, and they are wasted. In all the cases the waste is for a specific reason, not needless. So there is a difference between **waste** and **needless waste**.